# If the $T_B$ space has a non- Hausdorff compact subset , then $X \times X$ is not $T_B$? Why?

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $X$  is called $T_B$ space if every compact subset is closed.

The Cartesian product of $X \times X$ does not need  to be $T_B$. But, is the bellow statement  right?

> **If the $T_B$ space has a non- Hausdorff  compact subset , then $X
>  \times X$ is not $T_B$? Why?**

Answer (score 2):

If $(X,\tau)$ has a compact subset $K$ which is not Hausdorff, then $X\times X$ has the compact subset $K\times K$. Now the diagonal $\triangle\cap(K\times K)$ is homeomorphic to $K$, thus compact. If it were closed, then $K$ would be Hausdorff. So it cannot be closed. This shows that $X\times X$ is not $T_B.$

Comment: could you give me more information " why △∩(K×K) is homeomorphic to **K**"? Thanks.

Comment: @Alireza: The homeomorphism is the map $(x,x)\mapsto x$ and its inverse is $x\mapsto (x,x).$ Both maps are continuous.

Comment: Thanks,if △∩(K×K) were closed, why would K  be **Hausdorff**?

Comment: That's a result about Hausdorffness: If the diagonal $\triangle$ in $X\times X$ is closed, then $X$ is Hausdorff.